# Instantiate derived class with instance of base class?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a factory method for a base class (A).  It needs an instance of A to determine which derived class to instantiate. What is the Pythonic way to do this (V3+)?

```
class A():

    @classmethod
    def factory(a, b, c):
        foo=A(a,b,c)
        #...use foo to determine that B is the needed subclass.
        return B(foo)

    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        #  calculations on a, b, c produce several instance attributes
        self.m = calculated_m
        #...
        self.z = calculated_z

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, instance_of_A):
        super(B, self).__init__(?)         # How to construct superclass (A) given an instance of A?
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
class A():

    @classmethod
    def factory(cls, a, b, c): # first argument of a classmethod is the class on which it's called
        return cls(a, b, c)

    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        #  calculations on a, b, c produce several instance attributes
        self.m = calculated_m
        #...
        self.z = calculated_z

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):  # example for a subclass with the same signature
        super(B, self).__init__(a, b, c)

class C(A):
    def __init__(self, x, y):  # example for a subclass with different constructor args
        super(B, self).__init__(x+y, x*y, 2*x)
    @classmethod
    def factory(cls, x, y):
        return cls(x, y)
```

Usage:

```
foo = A.factory(a, b, c)  # this will call A.factory
bar = B.factory(a, b, c)  # this also
baz = C.factory(x, y)  # this will call C.factory
```

Maybe you can rename the `factory` method to `get_instance` because factories usually are classes dedicated to the job of creating objects of other classes.

Write a comment if you still have questions

Comment: Thanks for the response and thanks for the heads up on 'cls'.  I'm relatively new to Python, as you may have guessed.  Regarding the Subclass, I didn't state the question clearly.  I was hoping to have the constructor for B use an instance of A (instead of the individual attributes of A).  The problem is that A has many attributes.  Passing them individually adds overhead to the program and visual pollution to the source code.  Is there a way to instantiate B with an instance of A?

Comment: @SmarteePantz why should A know of B? https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/219543/should-a-class-know-about-its-subclasses

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Instead of A 'knowing of' B, I actually want the B constructor to be passed an instance of A.  Does the question make more sense with that clarification?